# "Simpler wick" in a split environment and undefined references

Tags: split

When I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x &= \wick{\c a \c b}\\
x &= y\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

then the output looks just fine, except that I repeatedly get warning messages

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `refmathstyle@1' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `refmathstyle@2' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
```

These warning messages go away if I remove the 'split' environment. Is there a way to get rid of these warning messages in a split environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It works fine for me. Which TeX distribution/version do you have?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik is right... compiled with `LaTeX`, `pdfLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX` of texlive and could not get your warnings... Possibly some more info like your `log` file is needed here.

Comment: Yup - you're correct. Running on a distro with everything up to date fixes it. Thanks!